# What is another word for the act of making a decision?

Tags: single-word-requests

One word for the act of making a decision. Not looking back. Moving on

Comment: commitment? deciding?

Comment: Determined or driven. Could also be strong-willed or single-minded.

Comment: Not second-guessing yourself.

Answer (score 2):

How about [committed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/committed?s=t)?

> Meaning - to pledge (oneself) to a position on an issue or question;
>   express (one's intention, feeling, etc.):
>
> *Asked if he was a candidate, he refused to commit himself.*

Answer (score 1):

The ability to do so is ***decisiveness*** (*noun*) and such a person can be called **decisive** (*adjective*).

ODO:

> **[decisiveness](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/decisiveness)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** The ability to make decisions quickly and effectively.
>   ‘the crisis will require leadership and decisiveness to resolve it’
>
> **[decisive](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/decisive)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1.1** (of a person) having or showing the ability to make decisions quickly and effectively.
>
> ‘Like Clifford, he is decisive and very skilled at pushing agendas
>   through.’

Answer (score 1):

[resolve](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/resolve)

NOUN

1. a resolution or determination made, as to follow some course of action
2. firmness of purpose or intent; determination

*or*

to resolve to do something;

> [resolve](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/resolve) verb (DECIDE)   [ I ] formal to make a decision formally or
> with determination: [ + that ] She **resolved** that she would never speak
> to him again.